# Symfony runs SQL INSERT INTO twice

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

i have a symfony application with two entities CONTEXT and USER, that are associated twice per many to many association:

```
class User 

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Context", inversedBy="members")
 */
private $contexts;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Context", inversedBy="managers")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="manager_context")
 */
private $managerOfContexts;

class Context

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="contexts")
 */
private $members;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="managerOfContexts")
 */
private $managers;
```

When i add a new user and add a context to the user i always get the following error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user_context
(user_id, context_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [5, 1]:

2 SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
'2-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

It seems that the SQL command

```
DEBUG - INSERT INTO user_context (user_id, context_id) VALUES (?, ?)
DEBUG - INSERT INTO user_context (user_id, context_id) VALUES (?, ?)
```

is performed twice.
I just can't figure out why.

I already cleared the symfony cache, created the database new and also cleared the browsers cache.

Thank you for any help!

---

Here is the code where i persist the user entity:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/user/new", name="admin_user_new")
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    // 1) build the form
    $user = new User();


    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user, array('is_mode' => 'save','contexts' => null));

    // 2) handle the submit (will only happen on POST)
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // 3) Encode the password (you could also do this via Doctrine listener)
        $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
            ->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
        $user->setPassword($password);

      $user->addContext($this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Context')
        ->find(1));

     $user->setActiveContext($this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Context')
        ->find(1));    

        // 4) save the User!
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);

        $folder = new Folder();
        $folder->setPrivate($user);
        $em->persist($folder);
        $em->flush();            


        // ... do any other work - like send them an email, etc
        // maybe set a "flash" success message for the user

        return $this->redirectToRoute('tasklist');
    }

    return $this->render('/admin/user/new.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

Comment: Please add some code showing how you persist the entity.

Comment: What are the unique constraints you defined on the entities?

Comment: I added my code where i generate a new user entity. I do not have any unique constraints on my entities.

Comment: Please add code of User's methods addContext and setActiveContext. It looks like you add same entity twice...